# Authentication failed on the server in Android Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I tried all possible solutions and searched it in all platforms but could not solve this issue.

Please take a look to my code in github and suggest what is wrong in my code:

Edited link: https://github.com/swatiag1101/MapsUdacity

E/b: Authentication failed on the server. E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.

E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com) Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled. Ensure that the following Android Key exists: API Key:  Android Application (;):

Comment: Which hashkey you used while generating the app key for google maps. Default or using your keystore ?

Comment: i think, there is a problem with you hashkey. Can you please follow this tutorial? http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html#google-maps

Comment: I used the keystore haskkey

Answer (score 0):

Your application is failing to authorize its API key with Google's Servers. If you have created an API Console Project you need to ensure that you:

1. Have enabled the Google Maps Android V2 API in the API Console Project
2. The console project to use the package name you have defined in your Android Manifest
3. Have set the SHA-1 in the API Console Project to match the Keystore used to sign the APK (note every person has a different default keystore that needs to be shared if you are collaborating)